# why iam not able to install npm package cordova-res in ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am not able to install package **cordova-res in ionic 5.2.4v** and getting the error below.

**Command:** cordova-res

```
 C:\hanu\cordova-res-master\cordova-res-master>cordova-res
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 

'C:\Users\HanojBudime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova- 
    res\bin\cordova-res'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Any help/hint appriciated.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But After updating ionic-5v

it's working for me Okay.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem  Even with new builds. fresh projects. it does the same.

```
 cordova-res.cmd android
[cordova-res] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
[cordova-res]     throw err;
[cordova-res]     ^
[cordova-res]
[cordova-res] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\bin\cordova-res'
[cordova-res]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
[cordova-res]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
[cordova-res]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
[cordova-res]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
[cordova-res]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Yes me too..

**Any have solution for this ??**

Comment: Well I did a full clean using ionic refresh. I also found out my netwok security file did not exisits. This is required in the new version. I also installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-res try this is work for me. Most important make sure you have that network config file.